# My windows 8 recovery drive I created prompts me for "installation media" when I try to refresh/reset

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, installation, windows-activation

I created a Windows 8 recover drive on a USB stick. I can boot from it and get to the options to refresh/reset my installation. However, after I select either option it prompts me to "insert my installation media". It's an ultrabook with no optical drive. Windows 8 was already installed on it. I have no installation media to insert...

Comment: For refresh/reset to work you need an active Win8 recovery partition on your PC. Otherwise you need the Win8 installation media to proceed.

Comment: I see a recovery partition in device management: http://i.imgur.com/4R2HN7q.png

Comment: Then perhaps it's corrupted or files are missing...

Comment: Hmmm. Does installing Windows 8 fresh create a proper recovery partition?

Comment: Nope, Win8 Setup does not create a reset recovery image, nor does it prepare a recovery image partition. That's entirely your laptop manufacturer's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Windows 8 installation USB stick, that's the installation media. The Windows 8 upgrade software will let you create one: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271128

If you already have the Windows 8 ISO file, you can also create the bootable USB stick by using the Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool (Works with Windows 8) http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msus/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool/